# What is meaning of write at zero after method call?

Tags: gcc, assembly, intel, disassembly

I've got a sigfault inside a shared library. There is a stack trace.

```
(_bad_func+0x3dd)
```

Function definition is:

```
000000000008b030 <_bad_func>:
```

I found the problem place (0x08b950 + 0x3dd => 0x8bd2d) and get puzzled.

```
   8bd23:   bf 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%edi
   8bd28:   e8 03 ca fe ff          callq  78730 <sleep@plt>
   8bd2d:   c6 04 25 00 00 00 00    movb   $0x0,0x0
   8bd34:   00 
   8bd35:   e9 3a ff ff ff          jmpq   8bc74 <xxx+0x324>
```

I think "movb $0x0,0x0" is always fails. It writes 0 literal to nullptr.
Why did the compiler put it here? Sleep function is pretty usual system one.
I guess it doesn't touch its return address. So 100% after it sleeps for 3 seconds
the process receives segfault.

If there are stubbing bytes used to align next instruction why not are they just zeros (or 1 byte instruction NOP = 90).

This is Intel elf64 code.

The _bad_func looks the same from gdb.

```
gdb proc
br xxx   # stop and at the func after library initialized
start
disas _bad_func

   0x00002aaaaaf5dd23 <+979>:   mov    $0x3,%edi
   0x00002aaaaaf5dd28 <+984>:   callq  0x2aaaaaf4a730 <sleep@plt>
   0x00002aaaaaf5dd2d <+989>:   movb   $0x0,0x0
   0x00002aaaaaf5dd35 <+997>:   jmpq   0x2aaaaaf5dc74 <xxx+804>
```

Comment: *Why did the compiler put it here?* - maybe the shared library has a buggy statement/sequence-of-statements that translates to this?

Comment: That's a non-resolved external variable. Is that fromn `objdump -d`? Try with `objdump -r -R -d`

Answer (score 2):

Possibly it is how the library signals fatal errors - by crashing intentionally. Or, possibly, the zeroes are a placeholder for a relocatable address and are supposed to be patched by the loader. Try disassembling with relocation info:

```
objdump -dr libmylib.so
```

Instead of trying to track down the issue by disassembling, I would recommend using a debugger, such as `gdb`. It will show you the exact place of the fault, and the *actual* instructions (not placeholders) at runtime.

By the way, your math is wrong. 0x8B030 + 0x3DD is 0x8B40D.